# UITableViewCell as Icons ( Thumbnails )

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview, uibutton

So I have `UITableViewCells` which are like Rows stacked one below the other.

Can I `redefine` each row (from it's rectangular structure) and make it appear like an `icon` (like a square button or a `thumbnail`, as you call it ) instead of looking like a default row which runs for the whole width ?

Is it possible for resize each row to fit them like thumbnails ? or Should I just go with UIButtons ?

Well... I already have a good table structure. I am looking at making changes to my app at minimal cost. My best bet would be to resize EACH row to look like an icon, with a background image.

any help ?

Comment: Your question is very confusing. Are you wanting icons within your cells with clear backgrounds?

Comment: no I want the row to have a smaller shape and then look like actual icons

Comment: Have you checked that [tutorial](http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/04/easy-custom-uitableview-drawing.html) ? It says how to use images to draw customized UITableViewCell backgroundViews.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By design a `UITableViewCell` == a row.

To do what you are asking for you have to do a `UItableViewCell` containing a row of icons.

You could also think about using some existing component like the [three20](https://github.com/facebook/three20) `TTPhotoViewController`:

[image]

Comment: Yeah. Well. How is this done ? Is each row having 4 buttons ?

Comment: Well... I already have a good table structure. I am looking at making changes to my app at minimal cost. My best bet would be to resize EACH row to look like an icon, with a background image. any help ?

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand what you try to do. A row will be always as large as table. You can resize the icon and use a `cell.backgroundView` or just even a `cell.contentView` subview.